# how to disable a button based on the list control selections in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

I have 2 buttons namely "disconnect"- deletes a single variable as selected in list control and perform certain actions and "delete"-permanently deletes multiple variables as selected in a list control. my requirement is to disable the "disconnect" button if multiple selections are made.for this I need to keep the count of selections made. Can someone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for that - [CListCtrl::GetSelectedCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx#clistctrl__getselectedcount).

There is also a macro [ListView_GetSelectedCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774996(v=vs.85).aspx).

or you can send [LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761069(v=vs.85).aspx) message directly.

Comment: thanks a ton @mpiatek ! it worked with one line itself :)